# list() method on tkinter object(s) fails

Tags: python, list, tkinter

When it comes to wrapping a tkinter object (or multiple) in a list, there seems to be a descrepency between using the square bracket operators `[]` vs. the `list()` constructor:

In 1:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> list(tk.Entry())
```

Out 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1486, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

In 2:

```
>>> [tk.Entry()]
```

Out 2:

```
[<tkinter.Entry object .!entry2>]
```

This is quite confusing considering that `type(tk.Entry())` yields `<class 'tkinter.Entry'>` as expected, not `int`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list(x)` and `[x]` are not the same.

Comment: The square brackets are not operators, they form part of *list literals*. The `list` constructor accepts *any iterable* and creates  a list from the items in the iterable. Two very different things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have been told in the comments, `list(x)` and `[x]` are not the same.

The nature of the reported error is more interesting. When you attempt to convert an `Entry` to a list, `list()` calls the method `__getitem__` from the `Entry`. For whatever reason, this method is implemented as an alias to `Entry.cget()`:

```
x = tk.Entry()
x.cget == x.__getitem__
#True
```

So, `list(x)` calls `x.__getitem__(0)` to obtain the first element of the anticipated iterable. This, in turn, calls `x.cget(0)`; this, in turn, attempts to obtain the value of the widget configuration option `'-' + 0`. The latter operation is invalid and results in the error message that you observed.

Comment: This is to allow things like `entry['justify']` instead of `entry.cget('justify')` but it has the unintended side effect of making it a broken iterable.